# What is this class of bolts called?

Tags: jet-engine

They can be seen in many —mainly military— jet engines. Do these bolts recibe an special name?

[image]

[image]

J79: the fasteners are everywhere

[image]

EJ200: they can be discerned in the rear flange

Answer (score 6, accepted):

12 point flange cap bolt/screw. For high torque applications, less likely to be accidentally rounded-off. 
http://www.fbabolt.com.au/12-point-advantages.html

Comment: They are also make from an extremely heat-resistant alloy, so their strength is retained at high temperatures.

Comment: I agree that the bolts in question are some variant of the 12 point flange cap bolt, but these bolts appear to be more specialised. I think there may be additional specifications, such as material, grade, and stretch rating. If you look at the shaft these appear to be a form of stretch bolt such as those used in connecting rod applications in piston engines. We may need to consult an engine IPC.